# Getting an error with pagination - python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping so here I wrote a code for amazon web scraping but Im getting an error at pagination so could you please guide me how can I fix this error.
have a look at my code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=oneplus+8+pro&crid=341BPYMDWRS5W&qid=1606986946&sprefix=oneplus%2Caps'
s = HTMLSession()


def getdata(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text,'html.parser')
    return soup
def nextpage(soup):
    page = soup.find('ul', {'class':'a-pagination'})
    if not page.find('li', {'class':'a-disabled a-last'}):
        url = 'https://www.amazon.com'+ str(page.find('li', {'class':'a-selected'}).find('a')['href'])
        return url
    else:
        return
while True:
    soup = getdata(url)
    url = nextpage(soup)
    if not url:
        break
    print(url)
```

And I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\first\Amazon.py", line 34, in 
> url = nextpage(soup)
> File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\first\Amazon.py", line 27, in nextpage
> if not page.find('li', {'class':'a-disabled'}):
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Does the error occur before the last page is reached?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that `page` is `None` which can happen if the above `soup.find()` cannot find the attribute and therefore returns `None`. You will need to check if the attribute was actually found before you continue to search for something else.

So instead of:

```
def nextpage(soup):
    page = soup.find('ul', {'class':'a-pagination'})
    if not page.find('li', {'class':'a-disabled a-last'}):
        url = 'https://www.amazon.com'+ str(page.find('li', {'class':'a-selected'}).find('a')['href'])
        return url
    else:
        return
```

it should look like this:

```
def nextpage(soup):
    page = soup.find('ul', {'class':'a-pagination'})
    if page is None:
        # page not found; return or do something else
        return
    elif not page.find('li', {'class':'a-disabled a-last'}):
        url = 'https://www.amazon.com'+ str(page.find('li', {'class':'a-selected'}).find('a')['href'])
        return url
    else:
        return
```